# Remove lines containing a string from all files in directory

Tags: linux, string, grep, match

My server has been infected with malware. I have upgraded my Linux server to the latest version and no new files are being infected, but I need to clean up all the files now.

I can locate all the files doing the following:

```
grep -H "gzinflate(base64_decode" /home/website/data/private/assets/ -R | cut -d: -f1
```

But, I want to now delete the line containing `gzinflate(base64_decode` in every single file.

Comment: please try `sed -i '/pattern/d' file`

Comment: As others answered, you cannot be sure that your server is not still infected, if you keep some data from the previously infected system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `sed -i '/gzinflate(base64_decode/d'` to delete those matching line in a file:

```
... | xargs -I'{}' sed -i '/gzinflate(base64_decode/d' '{}'
```

Note: You really want to be using `grep -Rl` not `grep -RH .. | cut -d: -f1` as `-l` lists the matching filenames only so you don't need to pipe to `cut`.

Warning: You should really be concerned about the deeper issue of security here, I wouldn't trust the system at all now, you don't know what backdoors are open or what files may still be infected.

Comment: Hi Sudo, so are you saying it should be

grep -H "gzinflate(base64_decode" /home/website/data/private/assets/ -R | xargs -I'{}' sed -i '/gzinflate(base64_decode/d' '{}'

Comment: Almost you want `grep -Rl "gzinflate(base64_decode" /home/website/data/private/assets/ | xargs -I'{}' sed -i '/gzinflate(base64_decode/d' '{}' 
`

Comment: Hi Sudo,

Are you saying it should be

`grep -H "gzinflate(base64_decode" /home/website/data/private/assets/ -R | xargs -I'{}' sed -i '/gzinflate(base64_decode/d' '{}'`

Comment: Just switch `-H` with `-l` and you got it.

Comment: Tried testing it locally and I get `sed: 1: "/Users/anton/Desktop/sq ...": command a expects \ followed by text`

Comment: I am not saying I trust the system completely, but I would still need to clean up my data files even if I do set up my server from scratch. Before the upgrade, new files would be infected daily. For the last 7 days however, no new files were infected. So I just want to clean it up and monitor it for awhile.

Comment: @AntonPalitsyn what version of `sed` are you running, do `sed --version` this work fine under `GNU Sed`!?

Comment: Sudo, just got it. I was testing it on a mac. Worked perfectly on linux. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AntonPalitsyn I knew it, damn `BSD sed` on Mac haha.. Do a clean system install! Your machine may have multiple backdoors now and could be used for any number of unwanted activities.

Comment: Sudo, I strongly believe that the issue was with the CMS rather than the os, as there are other websites running on the same server, but only sites on that particular CMS were affected. I have upgraded EVERYTHING that was possible :) Also, I had a public demo of how you could manipulate with content from the front-end. That demo was using a set of APIs, which would usually not have public access. Basically, you could do a lot more than the demo intended :) Like I said, I will keep an eye on it and should anything suspicious happen, I'll set the server up from scratch.

Comment: **on Mac**: `grep -Rl 'what' ./dir | xargs -I'{}' sed -I '' '/what/d' '{}'` as `sed`'s `-i` requires value or use: `grep -Rl 'what' ./dir | xargs -I'{}' gsed -i '/what/d' '{}'` from `brew install gnu-sed`.

Answer (score 0):

once you got these files using your command

```
 grep -H "gzinflate(base64_decode" /home/website/data/private/assets/ -R | cut -d: -f1
```

you loop throu files one by one and use 
     grep -v "gzinflate(base64_decode" file > newfile